# How to pass String value over popover in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I have one `UIViewcontroller` and one custom `UIPopovercontroller`.

I am not able to pass `NSString` value over that `UIPopovercontroller` class.

here is sample code.

```
  UINavigationController* contentViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoveToObjectViewController"]];
popoverController = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
    popoverController.delegate = self;
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectZero inView:nil permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionNone animated:YES];
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a property for your WYPopoverController and set it before you present it

WYPopoverController.h

```
@interface WYPopoverController : UIPopoverController

... 

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME;

@end
```

... file where you use it

```
popoverController = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController]; 

popoverController.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME=@"Some serious shit";

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectZero inView:nil permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionNone animated:YES];
```

Comment: I use your code and I pass the value but I get null value. I did on this way. I create a property in MoveToObjectViewcontroller. class file  and then write in viewdidload method. label.text=self.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME;

Comment: MoveToObjectViewcontroller it's a your UINavigationController from storyboard as i understand. 

you should use your class name as type instead UINavigationController and set property to it  instead of WYPopoverController instance

Comment: when I use MoveToobjectViewController instead of UINavigationController it not work. I perform in this way.popoverController.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME=@"Hit";
    
    NSLog(@"Your :-%@",popoverController.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME);
It display the value. and after that I use label1.text=self.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME; I use this in MoveToObjectViewController class. pleas help me 
then it shows  null.

Comment: i try to guess. 
instance of MoveToobjectViewController is a root view for your UINavigationController.

In that case you should get it using next code

`MoveToobjectViewController * myFVC = contentViewController.viewControllers[0];
    myFVC.YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME=@"Hit";`